# How to add Mac built in sound in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program in Tkinter and I want to use the Mac built-in sound for my buttons when it's clicked? I don't want to download and use the outside music because when I click a button, It responses the music very slow. How can I add built in sounds in Tkinter on Mac? Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `winsound` library . The full documentation:- [Click Here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/winsound.html)

```
import winsound
# Play Windows exit sound.
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

Comment: The OP said they use `tkinter`, hence this will freeze the GUI. You need `winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

Comment: But I am using a Mac, not Windows

Comment: @HuyVuQuang It works in Mac also; Search google

Comment: I tried 'pip install winsound' and I have been searching for hours. No result

Comment: Even in the Python official doc link you provided, `winsound` is under `MS Windows Specific Services` section.